# Pass a model as parameter to FileStreamResult

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, filestreamresult

I want to pass a model as parameter to FileStreamResult in my controller but I get null. This the controller file where I want to get my model in m

```
[HttpPost]
            public FileStreamResult GETPdf(MarkModel m)// here i want value from my view 
            {
                var MarkRe = new List<Mark>();
                var mark = new List<MarkModel>();
                using (StudentInfoSystemEntities db = new StudentInfoSystemEntities())
                {
                    mark = (from e in db.Marks
                            from s in db.Students
                            where e.StudentId == s.ID
                            && e.StudentId == m.StudentId
                            select new MarkModel
```

This is my view from where i want to send value to controller

```
<div class="editor-field">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.StudentId, @ViewBag.Students as List<SelectListItem>)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.StudentId)
            </div>
            <div>
                Export Data : @Html.ActionLink("Export to PDF", "GETPdf", "GetMarkRec")
            </div>
```

Comment: where are you passing your model as a parameter to the FileStreamResult?

Comment: public FileStreamResult GETPdf(MarkModel m)
here i am passing model as parameter m  is the parameter for my model in which i need value

Comment: where are you creating the FileStreamResult object..? this is just passing a model into a Action.

Comment: but in model i can't get value from view